# XCTAssertEqual this or that

Tags: ios, swift, xctest

Is it possible to test if an result is one of two options?

For example:

```
let result = "apple" //Could be "apple" or "orange"
let expected1 = "apple"
let expected2 = "orange"

XCTAssertEqual(result, expected1 || expected2)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
XCTAssert(result.isEqual(expected1) || result.isEqual(expected2))
```